# add checkbox in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms, telerik

I'm using telerik control in my project.
I want to add checkbox in drdownlist and select multiple values and  store in database. 
I m using c#.net lang. and it is window base application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using windows application then its better to use "RadListBoxItem" instead of dropdown list. It is easy to use and more efficiently used in Telerik.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            RadListBoxItem item = new RadListBoxItem();
            RadCheckBoxElement checkBox = new RadCheckBoxElement();
            checkBox.Text = "Item " + i;
            checkBox.ToggleState = i % 2 == 0 ? Telerik.WinControls.Enumerations.ToggleState.On: Telerik.WinControls.Enumerations.ToggleState.Off;
            //remove this line if you dont want to close popup on checkbox checked
            checkBox.ToggleStateChanged += new StateChangedEventHandler(checkBox_ToggleStateChanged);
            item.Children.Add(checkBox);

            this.radComboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

write the above code at load form or at your own desired location. Then write the below code

```
 void checkBox_ToggleStateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.radComboBox1.CloseDropDown();
    }
```

and the namespace used is `using Telerik.WinControls.UI;`

Comment: Also you can check out this link, http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/radmultiselectdropdownlist ..It will allow mutliselect in DROPDOWNLIST.

Comment: @snehal if any of the above answers is helpful to you then please mark it as answer by clicking on the tick mark shown before each answer.

Comment: in this code how to get selected value.b'coz in radcombobox can't display checked item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ItemTemplate` Property of the control that you are using and insert a `Checkbox` in it. then what is left is merely a matter of binding.

Assuming you are using a `RadComboBox` it will look like..

```
    <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollectionOfProperties}">
        <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding YourPropertyDescription}" IsChecked="{Binding IsPropertySelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: but i m working in window base application and this code is in asp.net.

Comment: set CheckBoxes="true" in RadCombobox

Comment: Oh.. my bad..
you might want to take a look here then 

http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource55-Checkbox-list-in-Dropdown-using-Aspnet-Ajax-PopupControlExtender-control.aspx