# Add checkbox in dropdownlist and this dropdownlist add radgridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm using Telerik controls on my project. 
I want to add dropdownlist column in radgridview and select multiple values. I m using C# language. It is windows forms application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add the code what you have tried and where you are facing problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add checkbox in dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188308/add-checkbox-in-dropdownlist)

Comment: It is perfectly clear what he is asking for. Here is the answer: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/gridview/details/mutiselect-drop-down-list-column-in-radgridview

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewcheckboxcolumn.html

```
GridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new GridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkBoxColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
checkBoxColumn.Name = "DiscontinuedColumn";
checkBoxColumn.FieldName = "Discontinued";
checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Discontinued?";
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
```

I think this i what u mean right?
Next time try to Google for answers first, it is way faster than waiting for an answer here!

Comment: but actually i want add dropdownlist with checkbox and this dropdownlist add  radgridview.

Comment: so u want multiple dropdownlists with checkboxes in it, in a radgridview?

Comment: no actually i want one dropdownlist with multiple checkbox.so i can select multiple value and store in database.and this all process work in radgridview

Comment: but this code using wpf and i want only in c#.net code.